# Problem with Searching Custom Help Content

Tags: search, custom, content

I have SP server 2010 installed and I have 'Search Service not Found' error and now started SP Foundation Search.
In the Search Server of content database, selected the search db which was created on starting SP Foundation search. I am not getting the same error but shows:

> "No results were found matching "matter".   Tips for better search
>   results:  Try a different phrase  Check your spelling"

--- Can you pls help me over here?

I made incremental crawl but of no use. In the crawl rules, i have excluded `/_layouts/*`. Is that of any concern? should I run full crawl or remove exclusion of `/_layouts`?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Does your crawl account have access to the site? Have you set up the User Policies for Crawling accounts? Can you search anything successfully?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. It is able to crawl and retrieving results in regular search box. I have removed exclude /_layouts/* rule and the pages inside the 'Site Collection Help' were able to retrieved in regular search but search inside the Custom Help is unable to find the content. Did not setup user policies for crawling accounts.